# Stop webpack from compiling multiple times on single file change

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue.js Single File Components with Typescript. For CSS there is a webpack loader that generates CSS stylesheet file from `.vue` files.

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
     test: /\.vue$/,
     use: [
       {
          loader: 'webpack-atomizer-loader'
       }
     ]
  },
  {
     test: /\.css?$/,
     use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
  }
]
```

The `webpack-atomizer-loader` generates `main.css` which I import in my `Main.vue` file as: `import './main.css'`.

Now when my change anything `Main.vue`, it triggers `webpack-atomizer-loader` which generates new `main.css`. But since `main.css` is dependency of `Main.vue`, webpack consider `Main.vue` changed and again runs `webpack-atomizer-loader` causing a loop.

`oneOf` seems like it could be used for my case, but I don't really understand how. Any pointers?

Comment: did you get this issue fixed?

Comment: Not really. I am using a workaround now in which I don't import `main.css` but inject it in the final index.html using `html-assets-include-plugin` in webpack.

Comment: but how r u doing the versioning of the file then?

Comment: That webpack plugin has the option of adding a hash while injecting a file in index.html